# Linear regression with a dependent variable that is mathematically related to an independent variable

Tags: regression, correlation, medicine

## Background

I have clinical study data from 500 subjects.
Measured variables (measured once in each subject), among others:

- $P_s$:   Systolic blood pressure
- $P_d$:   Diastolic blood pressure
- $d_s$:   Systolic diameter
- $d_d$:   Diastolic diameter

## Hypothesis

*Subjects with a higher systolic blood pressure ($P_s$) have an intrinsically stiffened arterial wall (their arteries are biologically remodelled because they were subjected to an increased blood pressure for a long time).*

Stiffness is quantified using stiffness index β:
$$
β=\frac{\ln(P_s/P_d )}{d_s/d_d -1}
$$

This index is based on the concept that the arterial wall mechanically behaves stiffer with increased blood pressure. The direct relationship between pressure and diameter in an artery is (assumed to be) exponential; β is the exponent of this relationship, which can be calculated using the equation above from a measurement of $P_s$, $P_d$, $d_s$, and $d_d$.

In other words, if a subject's blood pressure ($P_s$ and/or $P_d$) changes transiently, $d_s$ and $d_d$ change but β does *not*. β is intrinsically "corrected for" the blood pressure dependence.

## Naïve approach (probably wrong)

Make a regression model and see how β relates to $P_s$. However, the problem is that β is *mathematically* related to $P_s$ through the β equation. This means that e.g., any measurement noise (random fluctuation) in $P_s$ will result in 
$P_s$ becoming a significant predictor in the linear regression model...

## Question

How to determine the (biological remodelling) effect of blood pressure on stiffness index β, while accounting for the intrinsic *mathematical* relationship between β and $P_s$?

Comment: I just don't understand what distinction you are making with the phrase "mathematically related": *all* models posit some such mathematical relationship! Could you tell us more about $\beta$? Is this a quantity that you measure or do you compute it using this formula?  If you compute it, then please explain what you mean by "modeling" it, because such an enterprise would seem to be entirely superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With the term "remodelling" I was referring to the biological process where an artery adapts to its environment (e.g., becomes stiffer). I have added some more information about stiffness index beta. Yes, we do calculate it using the formula, which should make it *independent* of transient blood pressure changes. I would like to subsequently use linear regression to see whether subjects that have a different blood pressure (for a long time) show an increase in arterial stiffness (as measured by stiffness index beta). Hope this helps :). Thanks!

Comment: I"m afraid I'm still lost.  Could you explain the distinctions among "$P_s$", "$P_d$", "blood pressure," and "transient blood pressure"?  Where do "transient blood pressure changes" appear within your list of measured quantities?

Comment: Haha, okay. Back to my basic question, which I simplified to: do subjects with an increased systolic blood pressure ($P_s$) show increased arterial stiffness? I'm studying this in a cross-sectional sample where there is only one data point per individual. If arterial stiffness and systolic blood pressure would be entirely separate measurements, simple regression or even correlation would do the job. However, the *calculation* of my measure of arterial stiffness (β) turns out to (among others) involve systolic blood pressure...

Comment: It is strange that β is defined using Ps, but you claim that the term ds/dd  corrects this obvious dependence. To see the actual dependence you can start by plotting a "Scatter plot" of β versus Ps and then decide what regression function applies. It may not be linear because of the presence of ln() in the β equation. If it is not linear, then (linear) correlation is not meaningful, because it may be very low even if there is a high dependency between the two variables.

Comment: Would this be right--you view $(d_d, d_s, P_d, P_s)$ as a four-dimensional random variable.  In particular, its components are not necessarily independent; indeed, they're probably strongly associated.  Although you know that for any *fixed* $(d_d,d_s,P_D)$ that $\beta$ will depend in a given way on $P_S$, what you want to study is the association between $P_S$ and $\beta(d_d,d_s,P_D,P_S)$ in your sample. If so, the main complication is that the measurement errors in the independent variables translate into a complicated conditional error in $\beta$ that you ought to analyze more closely.

Comment: (Cont'd) The most important aspect of this is that the errors in $P_S$ and $\beta$ may be strongly associated.  Standard model fitting methods do not account for this possibility--and it can introduce biases in the results.  Therefore it might be well to describe your model of measurement errors (and possible correlations among the independent variables) in more detail.

Comment: Thanks whuber, yes, that sounds right indeed. What would be the way to take the association of $P_s$ and β into account? I am familiar with normal linear regression and mixed-effects regression in R (lm and lme functions). Would such methods be adaptable? Are there specific terms/papers/books that I can search for? Thanks!